# WPF MVVM - how to inject a service into the ViewModel

Tags: wpf, mvvm, modal-dialog

I'm fairly new to WPF and MVVM and I need to create a simple dialog feature that allows me to popup a confirmation message on the screen such as "Confirm delete?" with y/n buttons. I created a dialog service for this (which in essence is a simple wrapper around the System.Windows.MessageBox) and I'd like to use it throughout my application. As I understand, I should inject this service via the constructor of all my ViewModels like this:

```
public MainWindowViewModel(IDialogService injectedDialogService) // Dialog service dependency injection
{
    dialogService = injectedDialogService;
    ...
    ...
}
```

I declared `dialogService` in the respective ViewModel as:

```
 private IDialogService dialogService;
```

And then I was hoping to use it throughout the ViewModel like this:

```
dialogService.ShowDialog("Some message...");
```

Or, like this:

```
if (dialogService.ShowDialog("Confirm delete?", "Confirmation",  DialogButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    // Delete it...
}
```

However, I get the following complaint from the respective View:

> The type "MainWindowViewModel" does not include any accessible constructors.

And the following error message from the View when I compile the solution:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

This is how I correlate the View with the ViewModel:

```
<Window.Resources>
        <vm:MainWindowViewModel x:Key="MainWindowViewModel"/>
        ...
        ...
        ...
</Window.Resources>
```

And the data context:

```
<Window.DataContext>
        <vm:MainWindowViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

In case this helps, here is my dialog service:

```
namespace FIM.Framework.Services
{
    public enum DialogButtons
    {
        OK = 0,
        OKCancel = 1,
        YesNoCancel = 3,
        YesNo = 4,
    }

    public enum DialogResult
    {
        None = 0,
        OK = 1,
        Cancel = 2,
        Yes = 6,
        No = 7,
    }

    public enum DialogImage
    {
        None = 0,
        Error = 16,
        Hand = 16,
        Stop = 16,
        Question = 32,
        Exclamation = 48,
        Warning = 48,
        Information = 64,
        Asterisk = 64,
    }

    public interface IDialogService
    {
        DialogResult ShowDialog(string messageBoxText, 
                                        string caption = null,
                                        DialogButtons buttons = DialogButtons.OK,
                                        DialogImage icon = DialogImage.None,
                                        DialogResult defaultResult = DialogResult.None);
    }

    public class DialogService : IDialogService
    {
        public DialogResult ShowDialog(string messageBoxText, 
                                       string caption = null, 
                                       DialogButtons buttons = DialogButtons.OK, 
                                       DialogImage image = DialogImage.None, 
                                       DialogResult defaultResult = DialogResult.None)
        {
            return (DialogResult)System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(messageBoxText, 
                                                                caption,
                                                                (System.Windows.MessageBoxButton)buttons,
                                                                (System.Windows.MessageBoxImage)image,
                                                                (System.Windows.MessageBoxResult)defaultResult);
        }
     }
}
```

Can you please help me with this problem? If my approach is wrong, or not the best, could someone please suggest a better implementation for a dialog service?
Many thanks.

Comment: It depends of the framework, some are by convention.

Comment: I don't use any MVVM framework such as Caliburn or MVVM light, if that is what you mean. I'm trying to implement the MVVM framework myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your `MainWindowViewModel` is expecting a parameter, you cannot instantiate it in xaml. You need to override the `OnStartup()` in the code-behind of your App.xaml file.

---

1. In App.xaml remove the `StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"`.
2. In the code-behind of the App.xaml, override the `OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)`:

---

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
     base.OnStartup(e);

     var viewmodel = new MainWindowViewModel(new DialogService());
     var window = new MainWindow { DataContext = viewmodel };
     window.Show();
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Kostas. I gather that I will have to apply that to all my views. In the meantime I added this to my ViewModelBase class it works ok in all my viewmodels: 
 ```public virtual IDialogService DialogService { get { return new DialogService(); } }```
With this, I simply use this concrete implementation: ```DialogService.ShowMessage("Test");``` But I'm not sure if this is a good MVVM solution and I'm not sure if this means I will end up with lots of instances of the DialogService as it generates a new instance of the class everytime I use ```ShowMessage```.

Comment: I was just wondering, if I use this declaration in each of my ViewModels: ```public virtual IDialogService DialogService => new DialogService();``` and then use the ShowMessage method of the service throughout the ViewModels like this ```DialogService.ShowMessage("Test");```, would that still be wrong? Because it seems to me that this way the ViewModel dependency is clear and it appears to me that I can keep the code a bit more streamlined. Sorry, I'm still learning and many thanks for your help.